# In App message crashes application , when installed update

Tags: android

In my app message works fine but when I update my app with new version 
App crashes.
If I uninstall the existing app then install new then app does't crash
It works fine.

Error prints,

> 2019-04-29 14:16:34.060 26803-26803/? E/UncaughtException:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML
>   file line #15: Error inflating class 
>       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class 
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:742)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:810)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>           at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.internal.bindingwrappers.ModalBindingWrapper.inflate(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display@@17.1.1:74)
>           at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay.inflateBinding(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display@@17.1.1:350)
>           at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay.access$400(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display@@17.1.1:82)
>           at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.display.FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay$2.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display@@17.1.1:292)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6393)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)

I changed dependency of different version of In app

Comment: maybe you should be more specific, by provide what have you done before/after you upgrade the firebase version( along with your dependencies)

Comment: I only Changed Splash Screen image and launcher icon and some bug related to UI
I increases VersionName from 3.2.2 to 3.3.2

Comment: When remove In appmessage  then the app does not crash